# Can jqgrid use with jQuery mobile?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, jqgrid

I would like to display data from database using ajax, jQuery mobile and spring mvc.

Example: display list of the course name in the table.

I'm now using jqgrid to display the data but is there any other alternatives without using data? There are many in the forum but mostly use php but mine using the spring mvc controller.

Please anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if jqgrid works with jquery mobile, but for a normal web app you can use `addJSONData` method with `jsonReader` and `datatype` property set to a function. Below is a sample:

```
function cfgWixGenApplicationsGrid() {
    var cond = null;
    $("#tblWixGenApplications").jqGrid({
        datatype: function (postdata) {
            var orderByExpr = "";
            if (postdata.sidx != "") {
                orderByExpr = postdata.sidx + " " + postdata.sord;
            }
            getPageList(cond, postdata.page, postdata.rows, orderByExpr, hSuccPageWixGenApplications, hError);
        },
        colNames: ["Id", "Title", "Name", "Version", "MainAssemblyName"
        ],
        colModel: [
            { name: "Id", index: "Id", width: 50, sorttype: "String", editable: false },

            { name: "Title", index: "Title", width: 50, sorttype: "String", editable: true },

            { name: "Name", index: "Name", width: 50, sorttype: "String", editable: true },

            {name: "Version", index: "Version", width: 50, sorttype: "String", editable: true },

            {name: "MainAssemblyName", index: "MainAssemblyName", width: 50, sorttype: "String", editable: true }
        ],
        multiselect: false,
        pager: "#divPagerWixGenApplications",
        viewrecords: true,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "rows", page: "page", records: "records", total: "total" },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30]
    });
}
```

The `getPageList` does an ajax call, in my case to a WCF service. I think you can call the MVC url here.

The `hSuccPageWixGenApplications` function calls `addJSONData` like this:

```
function hSuccPageWixGenApplications(pageData) {
    var list = [];
    $.each(pageData.List, function (index, value) {
        if (!value.IsDeleted) {
            list.push(value);
        }
    });
    var grid = $("#tblWixGenApplications")[0];
    var pData = new Object();
    var recCount = pageData.RecordCount == null ? 1000 : pageData.RecordCount;
    pData.page = pageData.PageNo;
    pData.records = recCount;
    pData.rows = list;
    pData.total = recCount / pageData.PageSize;
    grid.addJSONData(pData);
};
```

Comment: but i need to do a mobile apps.. thats why i'm using jquerymobile.. i read some they said jqgrid can be used in mobile but most of the examples using php..